# R: reshape a data frame when more than 2 dimensions

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt, dcast

I am trying to cast a dataframe into an other one, see below for the examples:

```
> start = data.frame(Aa = c('A','A','A','A','a','a','a','a'),Bb = c('B','B','b','b','B','B','b','b'),Cc = c('C','c','C','c','C','c','C','c'),v=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
> start
  Aa Bb Cc v
1  A  B  C 1
2  A  B  c 2
3  A  b  C 3
4  A  b  c 4
5  a  B  C 5
6  a  B  c 6
7  a  b  C 7
8  a  b  c 8
```

And I would like to have a data frame like this one:

```
1  A  B  3
2  A  b  7
3  a  B  11
4  a  b  15
5  B  C  6
6  B  c  8
7  b  C  10
8  b  c  12
9  A  C  4
10  A  c  6
11  a  C  12
12  a  c  14
```

Where line 1 is calculated because we have A-B-C -> 1 and A-B-c -> 2 so A-B -> 3

The fact is that I can imagine a solution with some for loops on the columns, but I need it to time efficient, I can have 100,000 rows and up to 100 columns so I need something fast, and I don't think that the for loop are really efficient in R.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks you!

Comment: Just to add some clarity, Reyflex wants `sum(v)` for each pairwise combination of `Aa`, `Bb`, and `Cc`. So for the pair `B, C`, find every row where `Bb == B` and `Cc == C` and calculate `sum(v)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `combn` on the column names.

Here, I've used `data.table` for its efficient aggregation and for the convenience of `rbindlist` to put the data back together.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(start)

rbindlist(combn(names(start)[1:3], 2, FUN = function(x) {
  start[, sum(v), x]
}, simplify = FALSE))
#     Aa Bb V1
#  1:  A  B  3
#  2:  A  b  7
#  3:  a  B 11
#  4:  a  b 15
#  5:  A  C  4
#  6:  A  c  6
#  7:  a  C 12
#  8:  a  c 14
#  9:  B  C  6
# 10:  B  c  8
# 11:  b  C 10
# 12:  b  c 12
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1!
Just a little things: after testing it it looks like it is 'fun' instead of 'FUN' on mine

Comment: @Reyflex, maybe you're using `combn` from the "combinat" package and not the one from base R's "utils"? That function seems to have a lower-case `fun` as opposed to the base version that has an all uppercase `FUN`....